# Weirdest behavior from vue - commented code is running

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I have a vue project with firestore as database. I used to log in user with the following function:

```
loginUser(){
 if(this.email && this.password){
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(() => {
    this.$router.push({name: 'Index'})
   }).catch(err => {
   alert(err.message)
  })
 } else {
  this.feedback = 'Please enter email & password.'
 }
}
```

I compiled and ran this code and it was running fine. Then as per the console log suggests, I changed

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

to

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
```

Since then I have observed a weirdest behavior. Even if I comment out the code `this.$router.push({name: 'Index'})`, it will still redirect me to the index page upon logging in. I have no idea what to do. Although, eventually I want to send the users to the index page as they log in, it shouldn't work if the code is commented out! What could I be doing wrong?

Firebase config:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

Router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Index from '@/components/Index'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Signup from '@/components/Signup'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Index',
    component: Index,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Signup',
    component: Signup,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if(user){
        next()
      } else {
        next({name: 'Login'})
      }
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

I just rolled back from 
`import firebase from 'firebase/app'`
to
`import firebase from 'firebase'`

Comment: What I'm going to say is a bit obvious, but did you try to recompile? Or are you using hot reload? Did you save after changes?

Comment: Hot reload. I'm running it on VS code and when I save, it automatically recompiles the code every time. Also, I run the test apps in incognito mode, so that all cookies and stuff is cleared out. I tried shutting down the project, closing the incognito browser window, restarting the project and then opening it in another incognito window... Still no change.

Comment: Can you share your entire router configuration, as well as the code you sue to initialize Firebase (not only the two lines in your question). Thx

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, please see the updated question...

Comment: I am literally freaked out... I repeated the steps in my previous reply (kill the app, quit the browser, ran the app again, and opened it in the new browser) and it worked... Now the old code is not running anymore... I wonder what happened...

Answer (score 1):

By doing `export default firebaseApp.firestore()` in your Firebase config file you do not export Firebase Auth but only Firestore. Therefore `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` does not work and you are redirected to the default page/component in your router, i.e. Index

Modifying your code as follows should do the trick.

#### Firebase Config

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {....};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();


export { db, auth };
```

#### In a Vue.js component

```
//...
<script>
const fb = require("../firebaseConfig.js");   //Adapt the path according to your files/folders structure
//....

methods: {
  loginUser(){
   if(this.email && this.password){
    fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(() => {
      this.$router.push({name: 'Index'})
    }).catch(err => {
     alert(err.message)
    })
   } else {
    this.feedback = 'Please enter email & password.'
   }
  }
}
//....
</script>
```

Comment: I have a separate import firebase from 'firebase' statement in my vue component.

Comment: Can you show the exact code? Modify your answer to add the code pls.

Comment: Actually the problem is gone now... I just reran the app in a new incognito window and everything seems to work just as expected... I have a strong desire to find out what exactly happened, but I have to hand over the project on time too... So I'll look into it once the project is complete... Thanks a lot for the help.